# If $I_n=\int_0 ^1{\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+3}}dx$, prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} n I_n=\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, definite-integrals

> Given $I_n=\displaystyle\int_0 ^1{\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+3}}\,dx$ for $n\in\mathbb N$, prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} nI_n=\frac{1}{4}$$

Here is what the limit looks like:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n\int_0 ^1{\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+3}}\,dx$$

I am not sure how to go about this exercise, but I tried solving the integral with no success. I integrated by parts once choosing $u = x^{n+1}$ and $v = \frac{1}{x+3}$ and this is what I got.
$$I_n=\ln 4-(n+1)\int_0^1{x^n\ln(x+3)}\,dx$$
I don't know how to proceed. I was asked previously to prove that $I_{n+1}+3I_n=\frac{1}{n+2}$, do you think this can be used somehow? I tried solving for $I_n$ but I don't see how it can help because of the $I_{n+1}$ that is left over? Help me out, please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that

$$I_{n+1}-I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1}(x-1)}{x+3} \text{d}x \leq 0$$

so the sequence $\left(I_n\right)_{n\ge 1}$ is decreasing. Also:

$$3I_n+I_{n+1} = \int_0^1 \frac{3x^{n+1}+x^{n+2}}{x+3}\text{d}x = \int_0^1 x^{n+1} \text{d}x = \frac{1}{n+2}$$

Now since the sequence is decreasing we have $I_{n+1} \leq I_{n}$. Therefore:

$$3I_n+I_{n+1}\leq 3I_n+I_n= 4I_n\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

Similarly, because $I_n \leq I_{n-1} \Rightarrow 3I_n \leq 3I_{n-1}$, we have:

$$4I_n = 3I_n + I_n \leq 3I_{n-1}+I_n\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Chaining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get:

$$3I_{n}+I_{n+1} \leq 4I_n \leq 3I_{n-1}+I_{n}$$

or

$$\frac{1}{n+2} \leq 4I_n \leq \frac{1}{n+1}$$

which implies

$$\frac{n}{4(n+2)} \leq nI_n \leq \frac{n}{4(n+1)}$$

From the squeeze theorem, it follows that:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} nI_n = \frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: This was really useful, thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a couple of questions please. You said "Therefore (from the decreasing monotony): $3I_{n+1}+I_n \leq 4I_n \leq 3I_{n-1}+I_{n}$. I see how you got to this expression, but the next one I just can't figure out. $\frac{1}{n+2} \leq 4I_n \leq \frac{1}{n+1}$. I know that previous to that we had $3I_n+I_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+2}$ but how is $3I_n+I_{n+1}$ the same as $3I_{n+1}+I_n$?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo on my part, it should be $3I_{n}+I_{n+1} $ on the left side. I edited.

Comment: Okay. Now I don't really know how did you come with the first expression: $3I_{n}+I_{n+1} \leq 4I_n \leq 3I_{n-1}+I_{n}$. Because you initially wrote $3I_{n+1} + I_n \leq 4I_n \leq 3I_{n-1} + I_n$ and that would be the same as $3I_{n+1} < 3I_n <3I_{n-1}$ and this made sense to me. I am trying to understand.

Comment: The left inequality is equivalent (after subtracting $3I_n$) with $I_{n+1} \leq I_n$, and the right inequality is equivalent (after subtracting $I_n$) with $3I_n \leq 3I_{n-1}$ or $I_n \leq I_{n-1}$. Both of these inequalities are true because $I_n$ is decreasing, id est $I_{n+1}\leq I_{n} \leq I_{n-1}$. I'm here if there's something else that's not clear.

Comment: I really appreciate you take the time to clear things out for me. I still have a question. When you go from $3I_{n}+I_{n+1} \leq 4I_n \leq 3I_{n-1}+I_{n}$ to $\frac{1}{n+2} \leq 4I_n \leq \frac{1}{n+1}$, how do you figure that $3I_{n-1}+I_n$ is equal to $\frac{1}{n+1}$. I don't know how stupid these questions seem to you, but I just want to understand how to solve this kind of exercises by myself when I come across them.

Comment: That's because I have already shown the recurrence formula $3I_n+I_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{n+2}$ is true for any integer $n$. So just set $n \to n-1$ in the recurrence formula to get $3I_{n-1}+I_n = \dfrac{1}{n+1}$. Or you can repeat the process in the second line: $3I_{n-1}+I_{n} = \int_0^1 \frac{3x^{n}+x^{n+1}}{x+3}\text{d}x = \int_0^1 x^{n} \text{d}x = \frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: Okay, it really is all clear now, I can't thank you enough for your time! <3

Comment: Very clever solution. +1

Answer (score 5):

Put $t=x^{n}$. We get $nI_n=\int_0^{1} \frac {y^{1/n}} {{y^{1/n}+3}} \to \frac 1 4$ because $\frac {y^{1/n}} {{y^{1/n}+3}} \to \frac  1 4$ and $0 <\frac {y^{1/n}} {{y^{1/n}+3}} <1$. [Use DCT to justify interchange of limit and integral].

Answer (score 4):

You can also calculate the limit directly without any recursions  using partial integration as follows:

\begin{eqnarray} n\int_0 ^1{\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+3}}dx
& = & \int_0^1 \frac{(n+1)x^n\cdot x - x^{n+1}}{x+3}dx\\
& = & \underbrace{\int_0^1 (n+1)x^n \left(1-\frac 3{x+3}\right)dx}_{J_n} - \underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1}}{x+3}dx}_{\leq \frac 1{3(n+2)}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\rightarrow}0}\\
\end{eqnarray}

So, it is enough to evaluate $J_n$ using partial integration:
\begin{eqnarray} J_n
& = & \underbrace{\left[x^{n+1}\left(1-\frac 3{x+3}\right)\right]_0^1}_{=\frac 14} - \underbrace{\int_0^1x^{n+1}\frac{3}{(x+3)^2}dx}_{\leq \frac 1{3(n+2)}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\rightarrow}0} \\
& \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\rightarrow} & \frac 14
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1\frac{x^{n+1}}{x+3}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\vphantom{\frac1{x^{\frac12}}}\ \ \frac{n}{n+2}\ \ }_1\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac1{x^{\frac1{n+2}}+3}\,\mathrm{d}x}_{1/4}\tag1\\
&=\frac14\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto x^{\frac1{n+2}}$
$(2)$: Dominated Convergence

Answer (score 2):

By writing $n I_n = \frac{n}{n+2} \cdot (n+2)I_n$ and noting that $\frac{n}{n+2} \to 1$, it suffices to show that $(n+2)I_n$ converges to $\frac{1}{4}$. However, by integration by parts,

\begin{align*}
(n+2) I_n
&= \int_{0}^{1} (n+2)x^{n+1} \cdot \frac{1}{x+3} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \underbrace{\left[ x^{n+2} \cdot \frac{1}{x+3} \right]_{0}^{1}}_{=\frac{1}{4}} + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n+2}}{(x+3)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Moreover, from the inequality $0\leq \frac{1}{(x+3)^2} \leq \frac{1}{9}$ which holds true for $x \in [0, 1]$, we get

$$ 0 \leq \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n+2}}{(x+3)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \leq \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{n+2}}{9} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{9(n+3)}. $$

Combining altogether, we get

$$ \frac{1}{4} \leq (n+2)I_n \leq \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{9(n+3)} $$

and therefore $(n+2) I_n \to \frac{1}{4}$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{n\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n + 1} \over x + 3}}
\,\dd x} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - x}^{n + 1} \over
\pars{1 - x} + 3}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\int_{0}^{1}
{\expo{\pars{n + 1}\ln\pars{1 - x}} \over 4 - x}\,\dd x} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{n\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\expo{-\pars{n + 1}x} \over 4 - 0}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 4}\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{n \over n + 1} =
\bbx{\large{1 \over 4}} \\ &
\end{align}
See
[Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method).